# Restarting Android app after updating package with Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, apk, adb

I have an Android app that I want to update by installing directly from the apk on a rooted device. I use the following code to do that:

```
function ExecAdbCmd(const Cmd: string; out Output: string): Integer;
var
  Process: JProcess;
  Input: JInputStream;
  I, BufLen: Integer;
  Buffer: TJavaArray<Byte>;
begin
  try
    Result := -1;
    Output := '';
    Process := TJRuntime.JavaClass.getRuntime.Exec(StringToJString(Cmd));
    Result := Process.waitFor;
    Input := Process.getInputStream;
    BufLen := Input.available;
    Buffer := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(BufLen);
    try
      Input.read(Buffer);
      for I := 0 to BufLen - 1 do Output := Output + Chr(Buffer[I]);
    finally
      Buffer.DisposeOf;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      if Result = 0 then Result := -1;
      Output := Output + E.ToString;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I then use that to execute the following adb command (The function ExecAdb works fine for other commands, for example when just installing the package with su -c pm install -r -d FileName):

```
cmd := Format('su -c "pm install -r -d %s && am start -S -W -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -n MYACTIVITY"', [TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDownloadsPath, FileName)]);
CmdResult := ExecAdbCmd(cmd, CommandOut);
```

When I execute the command above directly via adb on my connected pc, it works as expected.
[image]
The package gets installed and afterwards the app closes and relaunches with the desired version. However, when I try to execute the exact same command inside the app itself with Delphi, it doesn't work. Even when manually restarting, the new version is not getting installed. The function returns 127 and not the expected 0 and CommandOut is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: During app installation Android kills your running app. Not sure what happens to the su child process, most likely they are killed as well. Not sure how to run a command "detached" like in `screen`.

Comment: That makes sense, I think. Is there a way to queue the Intent to restart on app exit? As in set the app to restart once it closed, however that is done, run the update which causes it to close which triggers the restart?

Comment: Would I need a service running parallel to the app to properly accomplish this or is ther another way? Currently as a workaround I start a restart intent with a delay before executing the update command, but naturally I can't react on the result of the command or how long it takes.